# Cannot get the contact attributes of Amazon Connect by aws-sdk Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-connect

I am using call recording on Amazon Connect.

I am trying to get the contact attribute of Amazon Connect by using the metadata value of the .wav file on S3 where the conversation was recorded.

This is my Lambda function.

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const connect = new AWS.Connect();
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    await Promise.all(event.Records.map(async (record) => {
        const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
        const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
        var params = {
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key: key,
        }; 
        const metadata = await s3.headObject(params).promise();
        console.log(metadata);
        const contactid = metadata.Metadata['contact-id'];
        const instanceid = metadata.Metadata['organization-id'];
        var params = {
            InitialContactId: contactid,
            InstanceId: instanceid,
        };
        console.log(params);
        const connectdata = await connect.getContactAttributes(params).promise();
        console.log(connectdata);
        
    }));
};
```

This is the JSON value of the .wav file (I hide my personal information).

```
{
  AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
  LastModified: 2021-09-01TXX:XX:XX.000Z,
  ContentLength: 809644,
  ETag: '"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"',
  ContentType: 'audio/wav',
  ServerSideEncryption: 'aws:kms',
  Metadata: {
    'contact-id': 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'aws-account-id': 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'organization-id': 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'
  },
  SSEKMSKeyId: 'arn:aws:kms:ap-northeast-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:key/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'
}
```

However, when I used Connect's getContactAttributes method using aws-sdk, there was no value in the obtained parameters.
Even though the parameter values are certainly included.

```
console.log(params)

{
  InitialContactId: 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX',
  InstanceId: 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'
}
```

```
console.log(connectdata)

{ Attributes: {} }
```

I want to know what {Attributes: {}} stands for.
Is there something wrong with the argument of the getContactAttributes method, or the output method of console.log?
In the first place, can't I get the contact attribute from the metadata of the .wav file?

There may be many mistakes because it is a beginner, but I would like advice for this.
Thanks.

Comment: In addition, the getContactAttributes method is based on this document.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Connect.html#getContactAttributes-property

And I have registered this Lambda function with an instance of Amazon Connect.
However, I haven't solved the problem yet, so I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been self-solved.

The connect.getContactAttributes method seems to get only the value of Attributes in the contact flow. I misunderstood that it was to get the JSON itself sent from the contact flow.

I found that the value of Attributes is set by posting a key-value pair in the "Set contact attributes" block of the Amazon Connect contact flow.